# How can I replace ios native app in app store with new app write by react native

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I have the native app written by Swift language already published in the App store. Now I rewrite the app by React-native, React-native can generate both iOS and Android version. What should I do to update the new version for the current app with completely different X-code project generated by react-native?

Comment: just use the same bundle ID

Comment: you should same bundle id and same app-store account and upload it to app-store as new version

Comment: thank you, I'm already upload to the appstore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the same bundle ID, increase the version number and upload with same account.

Comment: what steps are needed for this. all blogs on internet shows from creating a new account, app id and then uploading ..